# Appropriate optimization algorithm for constraints having NaN values

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

I am trying to solve a problem where some of the constraints have NaN values. Which algorithm can be used to handle this kind of problem.
In my example I have 3 nonlinear inequality constraints,
C(1)<=  0
C(2)<= 0
C(3)<= 0
If C(1) is not satisfied, C(2) and C(3) will have NaN value.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009234/can-i-use-if-statement-in-constraint-function-for-optimization-using-ga-in-matla

Comment: @BenI. I have linked the question I have asked on stackoverflow for more details, basically values for some of my constraint can't be calculated unless certain constraints are satisfied.  I tried using if condition (if C(1) and C(2) are satisfied only then evaluate C(3), C(4)), but I am confused what values should be assigned to C(3) and C(4) when C(1) and C(2) are not satisfied.

Comment: @BenI. Sorry I am finding it difficult to explain the question properly. Please do ask if anything is unclear in above comment.